# Perl Net::SSLeay post_https how to detect no response from server

Tags: perl, post

I have been using
[`Net::SSLeay`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SSLeay)
for 20 years to post data to `authorize.net` and receive the reply, as shown below:

```
   ($reply_data, $reply_type, %reply_headers) =
                      post_https($host, $port, $script, '', $form_data);

        @data = split (/\,/, $reply_data);

        $FORM{'x_response_code'} = $data[0];
        $FORM{'x_response_reason_text'} = $data[3];
        $FORM{'x_auth_code'} = $data[4];
        $FORM{'x_amount'} = $data[9];

if ($FORM{'x_response_code'} != 1) {...
```

`authorize.net` received the data and processed the payment, but my system did not receive a reply. The user got a server error, and tried submitting the form several more times, all which resulted in payment processing, but no reply from `authorize.net`. When comparing my logs with authorize.net's processing time, I see that there's about a fifteen minute lag time between when the call was sent, and when authorize.net processed the payment. All four attempts were completed before the first processing occurred. Authorize.net says there were no problems or changes on their end.

How can I suppress the server error and instead return a custom error message?

Comment: I'm guessing you mean the `post_https()` subroutine from [Net::SSLeay](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Net-SSLeay/lib/Net/SSLeay.pod). IT would be good if you could include that information in your question so we don't have to guess :-)

Comment: Sorry - yes, you are correct.

Comment: What is the server error? Is it from your system or from authorize? Is this part of a CGI application?

Comment: When you say that there was "no reply" do you mean your code hung at that call, or that the returned values were empty?

Comment: have you been in touch with `authorize.net` to see if they've changed things on their end? You need to post the code that handles the response as the generic `post_https()` call doesn't give us any information about what you're doing with `$reply_data`, `$reply_type` and `%reply_headers`.

Comment: Yes @Borodin, by "no reply" I mean that my code hung at that call. When comparing my logs with authorize.net's processing time, I see that there's about a fifteen minute lag time. All four attempts were completed before the first processing occurred. Authorize.net says there were no problems or changes on their end.

Comment: I think you've really left it too long to provide that information and people will have moved on. I suggest that you add it to your question in the hope that people will notice the update.

Comment: @ialarmedalien I have added thecode that handles the response.

Comment: @Borodin Thanks will do.

Comment: You've pretty much answered your own question already: test whether or not the response indicates that the request was successful, and then return an appropriate page. You just need to do the "return an appropriate page" bit. Without knowing what other modules you're using and how you're creating html pages, it's difficult to know how to create the error page. In your position, I'd have a generic error page template with `$response_code` and `$response_reason_text` fields that get populated with the values from `$reply_data`.

Comment: It seems to be hanging up, waiting for a response, and finally results in a server error. It didn't get to the lines after the post_https line. Should I use an eval? Would that keep it from resulting in a server error if there is no response from authorize.net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, your problem is that your local server is timing out before receiving a response from authorize.net, and from your log files, it seems that the response does arrive, but after a long delay. Although it is probably possible to configure your server to wait for longer before timing out (assuming you have control of the server config, etc.), 15 minutes is too long for a user to wait and would provide very poor user experience. Therefore, I'd suggest one of the following strategies:

- submit the form by AJAX and wait for a response -- i.e. translate your form processing logic into javascript and perform the transaction asynchronously. Looks like there's an existing [authorize.net JS API](https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/features/acceptjs.html).
- the old school method: when the form is submitted, fork a new process that posts the form data (e.g. using curl) and saves the response to a file. The UI would return an intermediate page informing the user that their payment is being processed, and would periodically check whether the response has arrived, either through a link the user clicks to trigger a test for the presence of the response file, or through automatically refreshing the page (but see these  [accessibility guidelines](https://www.w3.org/TR/WAI-WEBCONTENT-TECHS/#tech-no-periodic-refresh)).

Whatever strategy you use, I would get in touch with authorize.net and see if you can find out why the response is taking so long. Adding a note to users that indicates that there have been delays recently and preventing them from submitting the same payment four times in a row would also definitely be good!

Comment: You understand correctly. This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!